# Angular2 using interpolation in ngClass

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to dynamically add CSS classes in Angular2 based on variables in an array (created by *ngFor).

Using this code:

```
[ngClass]="['calendaractive': {{date.active}}, 'calendartoday': {{date.today}}']"
```

I get the error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 19 in [['calendaractive': {{date.active}}, 'calendartoday': {{date.today}}']]
```

I'm trying to do this in the most efficient way. My last way of doing this included creating the list manually without *ngFor, then running if/else statements to add classes.

Comment: From the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) here I think you want to use the third example. So can you change what you have to something similar to this:

    [ngClass]="{'calendaractive': date.active, 'calendartoday': date.today}"

Comment: @Mickers Thanks! This worked perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad that worked.